# Need help shifting latin square in Java

Tags: java, nested-for-loop, latin-square

I'm currently making a latin square that starts with a user-set number but for simplicity's sake I'll exclude Scanner code.

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
  
  int first = 2; // starting integer on square
  int order = 4; //max integer
  String space = new String(" "); 

  for (int row = 0; row < order; row++)
     {
      for (int column = 0; column < order; column++)
      {    
        for (int shift = 0; shift < order; shift++)
          {
            int square = ((column+(first-1)) % order + 1); //this makes a basic square with no shifting
            int latin = square+shift; //this is where my code becomes a mess
            System.out.print(latin + space);
          }
     System.out.println();
       }  
     }
  }
}
```

Which prints out:

```
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4 
2 3 4 5 
3 4 5 6 
4 5 6 7 
1 2 3 4
```

It's so close, considering the fact that it does start with my pre-determined first digit and it's printing only 4 integers.
The problem I'm running into is the fact that it's going further than my order integer and that it's printing double the rows.
Any idea what I can do to fix this?

For reference, this is what I want it to print:

```
2 3 4 1
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: It's entirely unrelated to your problem, but you should be aware that `new String(" ")` is redundant and pointless. `" "` is already a `String` containing a single space. `new String(" ")` creates a new string with the same content. Since `String` objects are immutable as long, they are interchangeable as they have the same content, so you should just use `String space = " ";`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the innermost loop `for (int shift...)` is redundant and it causes duplication of the output, the `latin` value should be calculated using `row` parameter:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int first = 2; // starting integer on square
    int order = 4; //max integer
    String space = " "; 

    for (int row = 0; row < order; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < order; column++) {    
            int latin = (row + column + first - 1) % order + 1;
            System.out.print(latin + space);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 3 4 1 
3 4 1 2 
4 1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: You are my hero! I knew I had been overcomplicating things.

Comment: If the answer is helpful you can upvote/accept it as described in Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)